# Module not available error when controllers, services, directives put into separate file

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module

I have an angular application where i have a app.run.js and app.controllers.js

Previously i was using one main.js , app was working fine but now when
i have separated the controllers and run.js

i am getting no module available error.

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Please see the fiddle for the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Starfleet</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://webstandards.delhivery.com/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://webstandards.delhivery.com/2.1.0/libs/ws/delhivery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="starfleet-app" ng-controller="pageController as vm">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webstandards.delhivery.com/2.1.0/libs/ws/delhivery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.run.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/app.page.controller.js"></script>
 
</body>

</html>

This is my app.run.js

angular.module('starfleetApp',['dlv-ng','ngRoute']);
angular.module('starfleetApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: './../partials/tracking.html'
            })
            .when('/create', {
                templateUrl: './../partials/createOrder.html'
            })
            .when('/singleUpload', {
                templateUrl: './../partials/singleUpload.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    });
    
   
This is my app.page.controller.js

angular.module("starfleetApp").controller('pageController', function($scope, $uibModal, $log, $document, $rootScope) {


});
    

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change your `angular.module("starfleetApp")` to `angular.module("starfleet-app")`?

according to your html and JS, you are using wrong module name. this might fix your error.

**EDIT**

working code
http://jsbin.com/komodukipe/edit?html,output